# Failed test for JavaScript palindrome

Tags: javascript, string

I noticed when I literally type the word test or dabd, it fails by saying "test is a palindrome"; obviously these should fail. I test other words like racecar, madam, cat, they all pass. I check from the left most character and right most character and go down until we reach the middle. What could be the issue?

```
function lengthChecker() {
    var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
    if (str.length > 10) {
        alert("Sorry. Your input surpasses the 10 characters maximum. Please try again.")
        return false;
    } else if (str.length == 0) {
      alert("Sorry. Your input is too short, and doesn't meet the 10 characters maximum. Please try again.")
      return false;
    }
    palindrome(str);
}

function palindrome(str) {
    var j = str.length;
    if (/\s/.test(str)) {
        alert("No spaces allowed.")
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j / 2; i++) {
        if (str[i] == str[j - 1 - i]) {
            isPalindrome('', str);
            return true;
        } else {
           notPalindrome(str);
           return false;
        }
   }
}

function isPalindrome(e, str) {
    alert(str + " is a Palindrome.");
}

function notPalindrome(str) {
    alert(str + " isn't a Palindrome");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById("checkInput");
    el.addEventListener("click", lengthChecker);
});
```

Comment: In `palindrome()`, you always only check the first character and immediately return.

Comment: Also, *lengthChecker* should return the value returned to it from *palindrome*.

Comment: *lengthChecker* calls *palindrome*, which returns either true or false. That value isn't passed back to whatever called *lengthChecker*, so what was the point of *palindrome* returning anything?

Comment: ok so in lengthChecker when I call palindrome(str) I should return true?

Answer (score 1):

In `palindrome()` you always only check the first character and immediately return. Fix the loop like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < j / 2; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[j - 1 - i]) {
            notPalindrome(str);
            return false;
        }
    }
    isPalindrome('', str);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you don't need to loop. You can simplify the palindrome test to just this:

```
str === str.split('').reverse().join('')
```

This splits the string into an array, which can then be reversed.  It then joins it back into a string so you can compare it.

I'd then put this in a ternary statement for modifying the message:

```
var notp = (str === '' || str !== str.split('').reverse().join('').replace(" ", "")) ? 'is NOT':'IS';
```

I added "str === ''" to test for non-entries, and I added a remove spaces test as well.  Now you've got a variable that you can push into a generic alert or whatever.  You can change that to read "true:false;" instead is you want to control more than just the text of the message.

The following gets rid of the leading and trailing spaces:

```
str = str.trim();
```

There are more edits you can make, but this should help you along.  Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/fudLdx0r/